# Deriving coefficient q in reduced quadratic equation using Vieta's formulas

Tags: quadratics

I have the following example of the use of Vieta's formulas in my textbook:

Let's have a quadratic equation of the form

$x^2+x+q=0$

The following conditions apply: the equation has two roots, such as $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$. 
We need to find $q$.

The texbook says the following solution is possible:

$x_1^2+x_2^2 = x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 - 2x_1x_2 = (x_1 + x_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2$,

hence

$x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1 - 2q$,

hence

$1 - 2q = 1 \iff q=0$

The question I have is why did the authors decide that $(x_1 + x_2)^2=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) 
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac 11=-1.$$

Note that in general, if 
$$ax^2+bx+c=0\ \ \ (a\not=0)$$
has roots $\alpha,\beta$, then the followings hold :
$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac ba,\ \ \ \alpha\beta=\frac ca.$$

Comment: Thank you, @mathlove, I totally overlooked this fact.

Comment: @CopperKettle: You are welcome.